# How to judge a Network environment is Only-IPV6 in iOS

Tags: ios, ip-address, ipv6

Since you know after June 1, app in iOS should support only-IPV6. I find a way that can change an ipv4 ip address to an ipv6 ip address. But, I cann't judge a network environment is only-IPV6. I already open a NAT64 WIFI by my MACBOOK, also use flight mode to make sure it's the only-IPV6. I just find there is an ipv6 ip address at first. Then work the code again, i will get both an ipv4 and an ipv6 address. I have no idea about it. Anyone have any idea?

There are my codes for fetch ip address:

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)localIPAddressFetcher {
    NSMutableDictionary *addressDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    struct ifaddrs *myaddrs, *temp_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in *s4;
    struct sockaddr_in6 *s6;
    int status = 0;
    char buf[64];
    status = getifaddrs(&myaddrs);
    if (status == 0) {
        for (temp_addr = myaddrs; temp_addr != NULL; temp_addr = temp_addr->ifa_next) {
            if (temp_addr->ifa_addr == NULL) continue;
            if ((temp_addr->ifa_flags & IFF_UP) == 0) continue;
            if (temp_addr->ifa_flags & IFF_LOOPBACK) continue;
            if (temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET) {
                s4 = (struct sockaddr_in *)(temp_addr->ifa_addr);
                if (inet_ntop(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family, (void *)&(s4->sin_addr), buf, sizeof(buf)) != NULL) {
                    if (![[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"lo0"]) {
                        NSString *address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf];
                        if ([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                            [addressDic setObject:address forKey:@"ipv4_wifi"];
                        } else {
                            [addressDic setObject:address forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name]];
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_INET6) {
                s6 = (struct sockaddr_in6 *)(temp_addr->ifa_addr);
                if (inet_ntop(temp_addr->ifa_addr->sa_family, (void *)&(s6->sin6_addr), buf, sizeof(buf)) != NULL) {
                    if (![[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"lo0"]) {
                        NSString *address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:buf];
                        if ([[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name] isEqualToString:@"en0"]) {
                            [addressDic setObject:address forKey:@"ipv6_wifi"];
                        } else {
                            [addressDic setObject:address forKey:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:temp_addr->ifa_name]];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    freeifaddrs(myaddrs);
```

`return addressDic;}`

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @user102008 thx for you attention. I need to connect a TCP request by ip address. So i need to know which address i will connect, ipv4 or ipv6.

Comment: Just always use the IPv4 address. You can use the IPv4 address with any higher-level networking APIs directly, or if you are using low-level socket APIs, you can give that to getaddrinfo(), and use whatever address it gives back first.